# progess bar or other idea for loading window

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, progress-bar

I have a `Window` that needs about 4-5 seconds to load before displaying its content.
There is a large query running to fill a `DataGrid`.
During the load the new `Window` opens but the `DataGrid` portion turns black for that short period.

How can I add a `ProgressBar` or something else so that the user doesn't think the application is crashing?

```
public partial class SqlCreatedReports : Window
{
    public SqlCreatedReports()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridFill();        
    }

    private void DataGridFill()
    {
        CollectionViewSource dataViewSource =
            (CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("dataViewSource"));
        // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
        // dataViewSource.Source = [generic data source]

        var manager = new ReportMadeManager();

        if (Convert.ToInt32(statusReportID.Content) == 4)
        {
            dataGridReports.ItemsSource = manager.selectReportDJVJ(
                Convert.ToInt32(statusParameter1.Content),
                Convert.ToInt32(statusParameter2.Content));
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(statusReportID.Content)==5)
        {
            dataGridReports.ItemsSource = manager.selectReportCriticalProducts(
                Convert.ToInt32(statusParameter1.Content),
                Convert.ToInt32(statusParameter2.Content));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a NuGet reference to [Extended.Wpf.Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

Surround your `DataGrid` with a `BusyIndicator`, using its `IsBusy` property.
Make `DataGridFill()` *async* and await on the heavy task.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow_ProgressBar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow_ProgressBar"
        xmlns:tlkt="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <tlkt:BusyIndicator Name="DataGridBusyIndicator">
      <DataGrid Name="dataGridReports" Loaded="dataGridReports_Loaded"/>
    </tlkt:BusyIndicator>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The MainWindow in C#:

```
private void dataGridReports_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridFill();
}

private async void DataGridFill()
{
    DataGridBusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

    try
    {
        var items = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var manager = new ReportMadeManager();

            if (Convert.ToInt32(statusReportID.Content) == 4)
            {
                return manager.selectReportDJVJ(
                    Convert.ToInt32(statusParameter1.Content),
                    Convert.ToInt32(statusParameter2.Content));
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(statusReportID.Content) == 5)
            {
                return manager.selectReportCriticalProducts(
                    Convert.ToInt32(statusParameter1.Content),
                    Convert.ToInt32(statusParameter2.Content));
            }
        });

        dataGridReports.ItemsSource = items;
    }
    finally
    {
        DataGridBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```